# How do I prevent boost::optional<T> from being constructed erroneously with 0?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

`boost::optional<T>` (1.51) provides a way of constructing objects that is very dangerous for my users and that I'd like to prevent. Let's say I have my own integer class and I want to pass an optional such integer and store it in some class:

```
class myint {
public:
    int m_a;
    myint (int r_a) : m_a(r_a) {
    }
};

struct myclass {
    boost::optional<myint> content;
    myclass (const boost::optional<myint>& arg) : content(arg) {
    }
};
```

and now, here's how users would use the class:

```
myclass(myint(13));            //correct use
myclass(boost::none);          //correct use
myclass(myint(0));             //correct use
myclass(0);                    //INCORRECT use, this easy typo
                               //equates boost::none which
                               //is not what the user meant
```

I'd like to understand what is going on here and prevent this behaviour.

---

Interestingly,

```
myclass(1);              //does not compile
```

---

`boost::none` is totally a valid value for my field, but having a `boost::none` sneak-up when the user is trying to type in a `0` is horrendously misleading and dangerous.

The intent might be a bit hidden since I'm not really rolling out a `myint` class and I don't really have a `class myclass` that serves little to no purpose. Anyways I need to send 10 or so optional ints to a function and deduping wouldn't work. (you can imagine I asked you for your age, your height and your wealth and that there's three special buttons to check if you don't want to answer a question)

---

I've posted an answer that seems to work below (built from Mooing's Duck & Ilonesmiz suggestion, but lighter). I'm happy to hear comments about it, though.

Comment: Ouch, seriously? That's quite annoying :( .

Comment: want you allow boost::none itself?

Comment: RiaD: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please reformulate?

us2012: This is monstruously dangerous for my application

If that helps i have the feeling that it's coming from the copy constructor of myint somehow.

Comment: If you would disallow boost::none, you may make constructor `myclass (const myint& arg)`

Comment: @GurgHackpof: if it happens with `0`, but not with `1`, that means it thinks `0` is the NULL pointer, which means it's being constructed with a _pointer_ constructor.  A quick check confirms that `none_t` is a pointer type, so yeah, it's using `boost::none_t`.

Comment: @Gurg Yeah, I understand your problem. I was saying that I'm unhappy with the boost designers for making this possible (Although I have to admit I don't have a better implementation myself.)

Comment: You are missing Mooing Duck's original int overload in your final solution. With that addition, the code you commented no longer results in a compiler error. You can see it [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/34tpjJ$0).

Comment: @Ilonesmiz: I understand this, but blowing up at compilation is not a bad solution for me: dev are forced to adapt but at least they're not caught unaware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (Inspired from Ilonesmiz) seems to do the job fine and is a bit lighter than the approach from Mooing Duck but still uses the magic templating trick.

```
struct myprotectedclass {
    boost::optional<myint> content;

    template <class T>
    myprotectedclass(const T& a) :content(boost::optional<myint>(a)) {}


};
```

Here is the [proof](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9e9e531e2117f941961823d3098dfdad-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94).
When C++ sees the `0`, it thinks "hmm, this is probably an int, but it might be a pointer to something!" (only for `0`, no other numbers) But if you pass that `0` to a function, it must decide on a type, and so it picks the default of `int`. Whereas, in the original, a `0` was passed to a function expecting a `myint` or a pointer (`boost::none_t` is a pointer). `0` isn't a myint, but it can be a pointer, so it was picking that one.

Comment: I see your proof, but I don't understand it.  From my understanding of the code, this shouldn't change anything.  From my understanding of your test, nothing appears changed.  With `myclass a(0);` it did not contain a value.  With `myprotectedclass b(0)`, that _also_ did not contain a value.  I fail to see any difference

Comment: I added more explanations to my answer to explain why and how it works.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Right, I messed up in the test, which pushed me into believing that folding in the template was working. Look at the code above (that I edited and I obviously fixed the test) and you'll understand why i did this mistake. The current one DOES work.

Comment: I can't imagine why this works when the original code didn't...  oH!  `const T& a` _forces_ `0` to be an `int` rather than a nullpointer!  Heh, this doesn't work on _any_ of the same principles as mine, despite the fact it certainly looks like it does! :D

Comment: @MooingDuck: I must say I have a hard time with understanding it too.

Comment: @MooingDuck: would you mind expanding on the `const T&` forcing `0` to be an int ?

Comment: When C++ sees `0`, it thinks "hmm, this is probably an `int`, but it might be a pointer to something!" (only for `0`, no other numbers)  But if you pass that `0` to a function, it must decide on a type, and so it picks the default of `int`.  Whereas, in the original, you passed it to a function expecting a `myint` or a pointer (`boost::none_t` is a pointer).  `0` isn't a `myint`, but it can be a pointer, so it picked that one.

Answer (score 3):

Do not let the constructor take a `boost::optional` I would do something like this instead.

```
struct myclass {
    boost::optional<myint> content;
    myclass () = default;
    explicit myclass(const myint& int_):content(int_){}
};
```

However when I am thinking about it I am not completely clear on what you are trying to achieve and what you want to avoid happening. What is the purpose of the `optional` member?

Comment: Even with a `none_t` overload, [this still doesn't work](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1f16afb966314f54c62cbe0fb892ce80-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94) :(

Comment: well I think the answer (after the edit) suffers from the same problem as the answer from FredericS: it does not scale to multiple parameters

Comment: @Mooning Duck thanks for the addendum, however my original idea was a class that is either in an initialized state or not. I still think a clarification of the intent from the OP is needed to fully understand the problem.

Comment: @AxelOmega: I think I clarified, see the edit above. Don't hesitate to ask if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Closest thing to this answer that I can make work is [this](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3982585ada10848cf10321611fdc275e-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

Comment: Why do you have to allow `boost::none`? Why not just allow `myclass()` or `myclass(17)`. I am still missing the intent, what are you trying to accomplish and why? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @AxelOmega: in the other answer, he hinted that the real `myclass` has _many_ members that get initialized, so he needs `myclass(0, none, 13);`

Comment: @MooingDuck,@AxelOmega : the intent might be a bit hidden since i'm not really rolling out an int class and I don't really have a class myclass that serves little to no purpose. Anyways I need to send 10 or so optional ints to a function and deduping the way you suggest wouldn't work. (you can imagine I asked you your age, your height and your wealth and that there's three special buttons to check if you don't want to answer a question)

Comment: Maybe `boost::parameter` can help you out. Only pass the parameters that you name. The rest default to `boost::none_t` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @AxelOmega: I'll be looking into it, sounds like a plan

Comment: @AxelOmega: I looked it up, this really feels like an over-engineered solution so I dropped it.

Answer (score 3):

This is uglier than I like, but it seems to address your concerns.  It works by forwarding the argument given to `myclass` perfectly to a pair of functions that take either an `int` or a `boost::none_t`, bypassing the implicit user-defined constructor.  This works because `0` matches `int` better than `boost::none_t`, and an implicit user-defined constructor is the worst match.

```
class myint {
public:
    int m_a;
    myint (int r_a) : m_a(r_a) {}
};    
boost::optional<myint> myintctor(int arg) {return myint(arg);}
boost::optional<myint> myintctor(boost::none_t arg) {return arg;}

struct myclass {
    boost::optional<myint> content0;
    boost::optional<myint> content1;
    boost::optional<myint> content2;

    template<class T0, class T1, class T2>
    myclass(const T0& a0, const T1& a1, const T2& a2) 
    :content0(myintctor(a0)), content1(myintctor(a1)), content2(myintctor(a2))
    {}
};
```

[Proof of concept](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c44259199bdc755d380640f31c7d738c-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94).  Modern compilers ought to be smart enough to elide the copy, but that shouldn't matter for an `int`.

Comment: mmh, that is smart indeed! However This is still a bit annoying since I can totally see myself forgetting to pull out this trick for the next function I write. works though!

Comment: @GurgHackpof: Really, this should only occur for `boost::optional<T>` where `T` has a _user-defined constructor_ that accepts `0`.  90% of the time you shouldn't need this trick.

Comment: you're missing a copy constructor (see edit above) but I'll go with that.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry man, I flagged that as an answer before noticing that it is not one. Problem is: Ì can't forward an existing `boost::optional<myint>` through this kind of structure. Look at my edit to the question and the attached example.

Comment: @GurgHackpof I haven't tested it thoroughly, but changing `boost::optional<myint> myintctor(boost::none_t arg) {return arg;}` with `boost::optional<myint> myintctor(boost::optional<myint> arg) {return arg;}` seems to work.

Comment: @Ilonesmiz: you're right! This salvages this answer (as per my edit in the answer above). I have no clue *why* this works though.

Comment: @Ilonesmizk: I think I found a lighter approach, below

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is only meaningful for optional `int`. One solution could be to provide two constructors:

```
myclass() : content(boost::none) {}
myclass(myint input) : content(input) {}
```

It's true that you lose a bit the advantage of `boost::optional`...

Comment: It's really not a solution. if you've got to pass two of these guys you would need 4 constructors and so on. I have a function with 10 parameters or so so this would quickly become unmanageable.

Comment: @GurgHackpof: I don't think there's any other solution.  `0` implicitly converts to `boost::none_t`, and there's nothing any of us can do about that.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: thanks for trying but I'm not all that happy with throwing the towel! (could roll out my own optional class, but that would be a pain)